# NetNamedPipeBinding in Citrix Environment

Tags: wpf, citrix, netnamedpipebinding

My WPF application is working good in stand-alone machines. However, when I tried to install and run it in a Citrix Environment, there have been some shared object issues.

e.g. if user1 logged into the Citrix Server and access start a new instance of the application**(his instance)** all is fine. But when user2 logged into his machine and invoke new instance of the application, he has **been getting user1's data**.

I know NetNamedPipeBinding's scope is global and machine specific but is there a way to address the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is probably "Yes". If you want help identifying a solution you'll need to explain more about the application architecture, what part WCF/netNamedPipeBinding plays in it, and how the WCF service(s) is/are configured.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Chris. I have fixed the issue by concatenating the current logged in user name (NT users) with the endpoint to make the address unique. This is working fine and without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by concatenating the **current logged in user name (NT users) or current process session id** with the endpoint to make the address unique. This is working fine and without any issue.

e.g. net.pipe://localhost/MyService/
 or  net.pipe://localhost/MyService/**System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId**